# uuid-ossp module for PostgreSQL 8.2 to generate UUID

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I am trying to generate `UUID` in `PostgreSQL 8.2`. From the documentation I found `uuid-ossp` module can generate `UUID` but it supports only `PostgreSQL 9+`. Is there any way to use this `uuid-ossp` module in `PostgreSQL 8.2` or generate `UUID` in `PostgreSQL 8.2` by using query?

Comment: 8.2 is drastically obsolete. If you're doing anything more than maintaining an existing install without changing anything, you need to plan an upgrade. Don't bother trying to backport this stuff to 8.2; start the process of preparing to upgrade the DB instead. Read the release notes for every `x.y.0` version eg 8.3.0, 8.4.0, etc. Pay particular attention to the cast changes in 8.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be confused about the packaging of that plugin for Postgres. Postgres 9.1 introduced a new packaging scheme called `Extension`. The idea is that the creator of a plugin does more work with regard to packaging so that the user of the plugin might do less work with regard to installation. The [Create Extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) command (a mis-nomer to my mind) installs a plugin into your Postgres cluster.

Previous to Postgres 9.1, you can install the UUID plugin, but doing so is not quite so simple. You must locate the "uuid-ossp" plugin appropriate to your version of Postgres. The plugin may well have been bundled with your Postgres cluster but not yet installed (activated). Within that plugin package find the SQL script used for installation. You then execute that script in your Postgres cluster.

For details, see [my posting to the Postgres mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/C5EBF511-835E-4F24-A4E4-6CC0119F48E4@me.com) and my blog post on [the old way to install](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2011/10/using-uuid-library-in-postgres.html) and [the new way](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2011/10/extensions-in-postgres.html) to install the UUID plugin.

I cannot find the 8.2 doc, but did find [the 8.3 doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/uuid-ossp.html) for the `uuid-ossp` plugin. I do not know if 8.2 had a version of the uuid-ossp plugin, but I suppose so.

---

Postgres 8.2 reached [end-of-life](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) two years (2011-12). I strongly suggest planning an upgrade.

As Craig Ringer commented, you should be doing only the most basic maintenance to a Postgres 8.2 cluster. Asking about UUID support suggests some major changes. For such changes you **really should first complete an upgrade** to a more recent Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function PL/Perl or PL/Python that generates UUIDs using one of their modules.

Comment: Or [PL/Java](http://pgfoundry.org/projects/pljava/) and [others](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/external-pl.html).